# Allow users to edit case comment

Tags: administration, case

Some users don't have the "edit" link available to them, how do I go about in turning it on for them?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable “Edit Case Comments” User Permission

[see this link for more info](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_comments_create_detail_page.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: The documentation didn't help much, but I found it, it's in the profile->App Permissions

Comment: documentation doesn't explicitly tell where to find "Edit Case Comments", but your post did help.